# Show loading screen until geojson data markers' style are set using Google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I would like to make the map visible once every marker is in it with the proper style.

I am using custom marker icons that is why setting the style of the markers is taking a lot of time.

loadGeoJson has callback but I want the map appear when the setStyle is done and not the loadGeoJson. I think, somehow I should make a callback for the setStyle event.
Unfortunately, I couldn't find a workaround with idle and tilesloaded google map events either.

```
function initMap() {
   var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: { lat: -1.54108, lng: 37.759902 },
        zoom: 5,
    });
   map.data.loadGeoJson(GEOJSON);
   map.data.setStyle(styleFeature);
}
//////////////////////////////////////////////////
function styleFeature(feature) {
    var icon = {
        url: feature.getProperty('icon'), //logos come from google drive
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(30, 30),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 30)
    };
    var chain = feature.getProperty('chain');

    return {
        icon: icon,
        title: chain,
        visible: true

    }    
};
```

Here is a working example of the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/6bznm32v/

It has just a few images for the custom markers, but still have a bit of loading time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the way to tell when the icons will appear on the map is to attach `onload` event listeners to the icon images, then remove the "loading" indication once they have all loaded.

Note that the code below assumes all the features have custom icons, the calculation gets more complicated if some don't.

```
var featuresToBeStyled;  // number of features in the GeoJSON file
map.data.loadGeoJson('https://api.myjson.com/bins/bdmco', {}, function(features) {
  console.log("loadGeoJson complete, "+features.length+" features");
  featuresToBeStyled=features.length;
});
var iconsLoaded = 0;  // icons whose images have loaded
function styleFeature(feature) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = (function(idx, feature) {
      return function () {
         var timeImage = performance.now();
         iconsLoaded++;
         if (iconsLoaded==featuresToBeStyled)
           document.getElementById('loaddiv').style.display="none";
      }
    })(styledFeatures,feature);
    img.src = feature.getProperty('icon');
    var icon = {
        url: feature.getProperty('icon'), 
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(30, 30),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 30)
    };
    var amenity = feature.getProperty('amenity');
    return {
        icon: icon,
        title: amenity,
        visible: true,
    }
}
```

[proof of concept](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GeoJSON_loading.html)

**code snippet:**

```css
#map {
  height: 100%;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#loaddiv {
  BORDER-RIGHT: #785e4f 4px groove;
  PADDING-RIGHT: 20px;
  BORDER-TOP: #785e4f 4px groove;
  PADDING-LEFT: 20px;
  FONT-WEIGHT: bold;
  Z-INDEX: 100;
  FILTER: alpha(opacity=75);
  LEFT: 260px;
  PADDING-BOTTOM: 20px;
  MARGIN-LEFT: auto;
  BORDER-LEFT: #785e4f 4px groove;
  WIDTH: 250px;
  MARGIN-RIGHT: auto;
  PADDING-TOP: 20px;
  BORDER-BOTTOM: #785e4f 4px groove;
  POSITION: absolute;
  TOP: 150px;
  BACKGROUND-COLOR: #FFFFFF;
  /* BACKGROUND-COLOR: #e7b047; */
  TEXT-ALIGN: center;
  opacity: .75
}
```

```html
<div id="loaddiv">Loading.....&#160;&#160;&#160; please wait!<br /></div>
<div id="map"></div>


<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var map;
  var featuresToBeStyled;
  var initialLoad = performance.now();

  function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 3,
      center: {
        lat: -1.54108,
        lng: 37.759902
      }
    });
    // NOTE: This uses cross-domain XHR, and may not work on older browsers.
    map.data.loadGeoJson('https://api.myjson.com/bins/bdmco', {}, function(features) {
      console.log("loadGeoJson complete, " + features.length + " features");
      featuresToBeStyled = features.length;
    });
    map.data.setStyle(styleFeature); //just once this is done I would like to show the map. Until it is not, I would like to show a loading screen
  }
  var iconsLoaded = 0;

  function styleFeature(feature) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = (function(feature) {
      return function() {
        var timeImage = performance.now();
        iconsLoaded++;
        if (iconsLoaded == featuresToBeStyled)
          document.getElementById('loaddiv').style.display = "none";
      }
    })(feature);
    img.src = feature.getProperty('icon');
    var icon = {
      url: feature.getProperty('icon'),
      scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(30, 30),
      origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
      anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 30)
    };
    var amenity = feature.getProperty('amenity');
    return {
      icon: icon,
      title: amenity,
      visible: true,
    }
  }
</script>
```